# Javascript : Create a new array of objects(B) from an array of objects(A) associated with each other

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Since yesterday, I can solve my algorythm problem.

I know that the title is not clear, so I will try to explain as clearly as possible what I have in mind.

What I want is to build from a table of objects(A) a new table of objects(B).

The array of objects (A) looks like this:

```
{
  id : "REC-001",
  text: "Facebook",
  link: ["REC-002", "REC-003"]
},
{
  id : "REC-002",
  text: "Instagram",
  link: ["REC-003"]
},
{
  id : "REC-003",
  text: "Snapshat",
  link: ["REC-001", "REC-002"]
}
```

What I want is for the object array(B) to look like this:

```
{
  id : "REC-001",
  text: "Facebook",
  link: [
    {
      key: "REC-002",
      text: "Instagram"
    },
    {
      key: "REC-003",
      text: "Snapshat"
    }
  ]
},
{
  id : "REC-002",
  text: "Instagram",
  link: [
    {
      key: "REC-003",
      text: "Snapshat"
    }
  ]
},
{
  id : "REC-003",
  text: "Snapshat",
  link: [
    {
      key: "REC-001",
      text: "Facebook"
    },
    {
      key: "REC-002",
      text: "Instagram"
    }
  ]
}
```

For the moment the only piece of code that comes closest to my goal is the following (everything else went to the trash):

```
 for (let i = 0; i < objectA.length; i++) {
   for (let j = 0; j < objectA[i].link.length; j++) {
     console.log(i, j, objectA[i].link[j])
   };
 };
```

console.log :

```
0 0 'REC-002'
0 1 'REC-003'
1 0 'REC-003'
2 0 'REC-001'
2 1 'REC-002'
```

Then I can't create an array of "link" objects associated to the main "id".

Someone can help me ?

Thanks,

Sam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var arrA = [
  {
    id : "REC-001",
    text: "Facebook",
    link: ["REC-002", "REC-003"]
  },
  {
    id : "REC-002",
    text: "Instagram",
    link: ["REC-003"]
  },
  {
    id : "REC-003",
    text: "Snapshat",
    link: ["REC-001", "REC-002"]
  }
];

var arrB = arrA.map(itemA => ({
  id: itemA.id,
  text: itemA.text,
  link: itemA.link.map(l => {
    var foo = arrA.find(a => a.id === l);
    return {
      key: foo.id,
      text: foo.text
    };
  })
}));

console.log(arrB);
```

Comment: I implemented your solution and it works very well. Thx

Answer (score 2):

This should work, Please confirm if you've issues and please also modify the variable names as need. ( It's a greedy solution and I have done no optimization )

```js
 var d = [{
      id : "REC-001",
      text: "Facebook",
      link: ["REC-002", "REC-003"]
    },
    {
      id : "REC-002",
      text: "Instagram",
      link: ["REC-003"]
    },
    {
      id : "REC-003",
      text: "Snapshat",
      link: ["REC-001", "REC-002"]
    }];
    
    d.forEach(function(key){
      let newLink = [];
      key.link.forEach(function(linkData){
        d.forEach(function(obj){
          if(linkData === obj.id){
            newLink.push({key : obj.id, text : obj.text });
          }
        });
         key.link = newLink;
      });
    });
    
    console.log(d);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could get the `id` first and then build the wanted nested arrays.

```js
var data = [{ id : "REC-001", text: "Facebook", link: ["REC-002", "REC-003"] }, { id : "REC-002", text: "Instagram", link: ["REC-003"] }, { id : "REC-003", text: "Snapshat", link: ["REC-001", "REC-002"] }],
    ids = data.reduce((m, { id: key, text }) => m.set(key, { key, text }), new Map),
    result = data.map(o => ({ ...o, link: o.link.map(id => ids.get(id)) }));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Another approach with a single loop with a closure over a hash table, which collects the values later.

```js
var data = [{ id : "REC-001", text: "Facebook", link: ["REC-002", "REC-003"] }, { id : "REC-002", text: "Instagram", link: ["REC-003"] }, { id : "REC-003", text: "Snapshat", link: ["REC-001", "REC-002"] }],
    result = data.map(
        (m => o => (
            Object.assign(m[o.id] = m[o.id] || {}, { key: o.id, text: o.text }),
            { ...o, link: o.link.map(id => m[id] = m[id] || {}) })
        )
        ({})
    );
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will solve your problem:

```js
let a = [{
  id : "REC-001",
  text: "Facebook",
  link: ["REC-002", "REC-003"]
},
{
  id : "REC-002",
  text: "Instagram",
  link: ["REC-003"]
},
{
  id : "REC-003",
  text: "Snapshat",
  link: ["REC-001", "REC-002"]
}];

let b = a.map( value => {
 return {
   ...value,
    link: [{key: value.link[0], text: 'Instagram'}, {key: value.link[1], text: 'Facebook'}]
  }
});

console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps you:

```js
var ArrayA = [{
  id : "REC-001",
  text: "Facebook",
  link: ["REC-002", "REC-003"]
},
{
  id : "REC-002",
  text: "Instagram",
  link: ["REC-003"]
},
{
  id : "REC-003",
  text: "Snapshat",
  link: ["REC-001", "REC-002"]
}]

function getArrayB(array) {
  const formatLink = (key) => ({
    key,
    text: array.find(el => el.id === key).text
  });

  return array.map((item) => (
    item.link ? { ...item, link: item.link.map(formatLink) } : item
  ));
}

console.log(getArrayB(ArrayA));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the power of the array methods `map` and `find` to transform the first array into the wished format.

The `Array.map` method is used to iterate and transform each child of the original array.

The `Array.find` method is used to iterate through another (or in this case the same) array in order to *find* a child inside it.

```js
const arrayA = [
 {
  id: 'REC-001',
  text: 'Facebook',
  link: ['REC-002', 'REC-003'],
 },
 {
  id: 'REC-002',
  text: 'Instagram',
  link: ['REC-003'],
 },
 {
  id: 'REC-003',
  text: 'Snapshat',
  link: ['REC-001', 'REC-002'],
 },
]

const arrayB = arrayA.map((mapArrayAChild) => {
 return {
  ...mapArrayAChild, // copy properties from mapArrayAChild into the new object
  link: mapArrayAChild.link.map((mapLinkChild) => {
   const linkObject = arrayA.find((findLinkChild) => {
    return findLinkChild.id === mapLinkChild
   }) // Find which child of arrayA has the key corresponding to each child of the current's link array
   return {
    key: linkObject.id,
    text: linkObject.text,
   }
  }),
 }
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayB, null, '\t'))
```

To decorticate what happens here:

1. We loop through the `arrayA` Array and thereby create a new array to which each child is applied a transformation

```js
const arraB = arrayA.map(functionTransformingEachChild)
```

2. At each iteration, we copy the properties of the child of the current iteration and paste it into a new object (using the spread operator)

```js
return {
    ...childInCurrentIteration
}
```

3. We reassing the link proprety with a new array that is itself created with the `map` method

```js
return {
    ...childInCurrentIteration,
    link: childInCurrentIteration.link.map(otherFunctionTransformingEachChild)
}
```

4. When transforming each child of the link array, we find the object `{ id: "REC-002", text: "Instagram", ... }` in the orignial Array `arrayA` using the key string of the current iteration (eg. "REC-002")

```js
mapArrayAChild.link.map(
    (mapLinkChild) => {
        const linkObject = arrayA.find(
            (linkKeyStringInCurrentIteration) => {
                return linkKeyStringInCurrentIteration.key === mapLinkChild
            }
        )
        // ...
    }
)
```

5. We return a new object (instead of the string that was previously part of the `link` array) and iclude the properties we need.

```js
return {
    key: linkObject.id,
    text: linkObject.text
}
```